# Photos not appearing in dash home, photo lense

Tags: unity-dash

If I load up ''Dash Home'' then click on the ''Camera'' photo lense, to view photos or search for photos it says theres no photos that match my search.

But if I search under the ''home/house'' icon photos are found.

Movies and Music work perfect.

Any one know how to solve it.

Thanks